# How to make active with color an icon switiching tabs

Tags: javascript

Hi there can someone help me how can I change the color of the icon depending on what I am selecting:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.btn-for-device{
  float: left;
  background: transparent;
     
}
</style>
<body>



  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button btn-for-device" onclick="openCity('London')"><i class="material-icons laptop-icon  w3-orange">laptop</i></button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button  btn-for-device " onclick="openCity('Paris')"><i class="material-icons laptop-icon ">smartphone</i></button>



<div id="London" class="w3-container city">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Paris</h2>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(cityName) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

That orange background I want to be able when I click the phone to make for the phone orange and for laptop to remove depending on which one is active

Comment: Where do you state the orange background property?

Comment: Can't you just add a .style.backgroundColor to your onClick event for the element selected?

Comment: I dont know how i am new to coding

Comment: Did you know this feature of SO which you can accept any correct answer of your question? @Lila

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the w3-orange class to the active icon no matter what method you use.

Below is one example to do that, but not the only way to do so.

You can try to find out what way you want to use.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.btn-for-device{
  float: left;
  background: transparent;
     
}
</style>
<body>



  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button btn-for-device" onclick="openCity('London')"><i class="material-icons laptop-icon w3-orange" id="icon-London">laptop</i></button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button  btn-for-device " onclick="openCity('Paris')"><i class="material-icons laptop-icon" id="icon-Paris">smartphone</i></button>



<div id="London" class="w3-container city">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Paris</h2>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(cityName) {
    var i;
    
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName("laptop-icon");
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
       y[i].classList.remove('w3-orange'); 
    }
    var z = document.getElementById('icon-'+cityName);
    z.classList.add('w3-orange'); 
    
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple. just update your function to use `this` (which will refere to your button) as a parameter and use this to change its backgroundcolor while removing it from every other button: Here is an example:

```js
function openCity (button, cityName) {
    
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    
    //remove orange background from every button
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName ('w3-button')
    
    for (var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {
      
      //find <i> tag of current button (always the first one -> [0])
      var i_tag = buttons[j].getElementsByTagName('i')[0];
      
      //remove class 'w3-orange' (background)
      i_tag.classList.remove ("w3-orange");
    
    }
    
    //find first <i> tag of clicked button (parameter 'button' of this function)
    var i_tag = button.getElementsByTagName('i')[0];
    
    //set orange background for selected buttons <i> tag
    i_tag.classList.add ("w3-orange");
    
}
```

```css
.btn-for-device{
  float: left;
  background: transparent;
     
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button btn-for-device" onclick="openCity(this, 'London')"><i class="material-icons laptop-icon w3-orange">laptop</i></button>
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button  btn-for-device " onclick="openCity(this, 'Paris')"><i class="material-icons laptop-icon ">smartphone</i></button>
  
<div id="London" class="w3-container city">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Paris</h2>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">
  <h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```